# Unable to load class OutputFileTask with Android Studio 1.2 and Gradle 1.2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading to Android Studio 1.2, I´m getting the following error when trying to sync my project

> Error:Unable to load class
>   'com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.OutputFileTask'. Possible
>   causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency
>     cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection
>     timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync
>     project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build
>     process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve
>     this problem. Stop Gradle build processes
>     (requires restart)
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle
>   processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java
>   processes.

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            consumerProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier "source"
}



publishing {
    publications {

        repositories.maven {
            url repo
            credentials {
                username user
                password passwd
            }
        }

        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifacts {
                groupId 'com.android'
                artifactId 'artefact-1'
                version '1'
                artifact artifactPath
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

I think there could be yet another gradle api change which is causing the old stuff to not work anymore.

How can I solve the problem to build my project again?

Comment: Did try what the "error" said? Try `gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies`  try and `gradlew -stop`.

Comment: The last stable gradle plugin version is 1.1.3. Use it.

Comment: On AS 1.2 I could not reproduce with android gradle plugin 1.1.3, but with 1.2+

Comment: Can't use Gradle 2.4 with <1.2.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using dexguard? I had the issue with an old dexguard version. Since I updated to 6.1.19 there is no issue anymore. (Currently using AS 1.2.1 & Gradle 2.4 & 1.2.3)

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here. After update Dexguard everything works fine.

Dexguard version 7.0.04
Gradle 2.4
Gradle Plugin 1.2.3